# HTML Cookie security

Tags: html, security, cookies

I want to run something by everyone. I'm trying to upgrade and do a major overhaul on a website and I've noticed something, when a user logs in. Several cookies get set like nicknames and a usernumbers. The website is an online store and I've noticed that if I change the cookie value, I can get other account's item listing. This is only if I hack the cookie value and change it by creating a custom program in .NET that will allow me to change all header info. To me, this poses a potentially massive problem security wise but I'm not sure if I am just being over paranoid or if this is a real threat. If it is a real threat, how can I be sure that the user is actually the user and that these cookies aren't being changed. So far I have zero evidence that this has happened before to this website. I remember reading about Yahoo! and that they got hacked by cookie forging. (I think that's what it was). I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself very well or not or if there is another place to ask this. If someone can point me to a resource or something it'd be much appreciated!

Edit (1): It should be noted that the cookie values are stored in plain text. This a bad move? Should I use this answer to improve security?  [Cookie Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529196/cookie-security)

Edit (2): Moved to [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152088/html-cookie-security)

Comment: Should be on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll move it over there then. As soon as the 40 minute wait is up I will move it. I'll leave it here for a little in hope of getting a little more insight.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it´s definitely a security problem.
There are different ways to solve that.

Just to give you an idea, what we usually do is when the user logs into the application, we return back a SessionID which you can save in a Cookie or any Storage.

The SessionID might be a GUID, and it´s going to be related to an specific user with an expiration eventually.

The SessionID is auto-generated on the backend when the Login occurs, and the only way to get a valid one is providing valid credentials.

You will be able to change the cookie value as you are doing now, but it´s almost impossible to guess a valid GUID, considering that you can automatically block an IP address after many failed requests attempts.